# | autodesk Forge | Export RVT into multiple 3D views

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge, autodesk-data-management

Is it possible to convert/translate/export RVT into SVF to get multiple 3D views by using autodesk forge C# library or rest API? By default I am getting only {3D} file after translation/export.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to your Revit file configurations, please follow the instruction of [Publishing Settings from Revit for BIM 360](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/publishing-settings-revit-for-bim-360.html) to choose the views you want to show in Forge, and make sure the view set is checked in the dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to change the rvt file configuration from forge C# library before upload and translating to svf and get multiple 3D views from it?

Comment: Unfortunately,  the Publishing Settings feature is available on Revit Desktop UI only. It's from the [Autodesk Collaboration for Revit Addin](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/getting-started/caas/simplecontent/content/autodesk-collaboration-for-revit-c4r-add-installer-downloads-and-verification.html) which is shipped with the Revit desktop release starting from Revit 2018. There is no API support (Revit API or Forge Model Derivative API) for this at this moment. We logged it as a wishlist item,`RVTLMV-217`.